# Looking for an error measure like MAE that weights overprediction more than underprediction

Tags: prediction, loss-functions

I am trying to evaluate my prediction results using common error measures like the MAE, MSE or RMSE. For me it is much worse if the predicted value is higher than the true value. If it is less, it is of course also sub-optimal but not that critical. I am looking for an error measure which puts more weight on errors like these (prediction too high).

Is there something like that?

Comment: Sure, you can define any such error measure, say $\sum_{i=1}^n \begin{cases}\hat{y}_i - y_i & \text{ if } \hat{y}_i \ge y_i \\ \frac{1}{5} (y_i - \hat{y}_i) & \text{ if } \hat{y}_i < y_i \end{cases}$. I don't know of any in common use; if you say a little more about your specific requirements, we could come up with one to meet those.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about something like that, but I was wondering if there was an already existing established model that is used for such problems.

Let's consider the following scenario:

We want to power a device using solar power and a battery. We want to use as less power of the battery as possible, so we forecast the solar power. If we forecast too high solar power, we will in the worst case not be able to power our device. That is why I want to penalize too high predictions more than too low predictions.

Comment: You could dream up any number of asymmetric loss functions, but probably the best approach would be to take your knowledge of the problem and use it to formulate your own.  That or provide more information so that others might be able to do this.  As stated there isn't enough to go on.

Answer (score 2):

> For me it is much worse if the predicted value is higher than the true value.

Here you're describing a feature of a [*loss function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function), specifically that it's asymmetric.

There are any number of asymmetric loss functions, which may penalize losses on one side more than the other.

Since you also say that you want something like MAE, that suggests you want something along the lines of the loss function suggested by Dougal in comments:

[image]

This is a perfectly reasonable thing to do if that reflects how your underlying loss function operates. As dsaxton points out in comments, you should not use someone else's idea of a loss function, you should use what suits the specifics of your problem. If your loss function is not linear either side of the true value, you should try to work out what it is, at least in approximately.